# picking items from array that contains integers

Tags: iphone

i am trying to have an array that contains 5 integers(0,1,2,3,4) called questionNumber
the questionNumber is supposed to end up with 4 so therefore i am trying to make a function to call randomly numbers 0-3 and go from one to another (add 1 to prevoius number) until they reach 4.
How would this be implemented?
many thanks

Comment: I didn't understand the question. You say random numbers and right after that you say that you should add 1 to the previous number... It isn't random anymore. I also see that it is not directly related to iPhone - this is more likely to be some algorithm question, isn't it? Anyhow, if you know the exact steps then try to explain the problem again.

Comment: Steps are get a random number sequence from 1-10 let's say. Make sure 10 is the last number in the sequence. Use questionnumber to see this sequence

Comment: You keep asking the same question (more or less) over and over. Please only ask questions once, and when you do, take your time to phrase them as clearly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use arc4random() % x; to get a random number from 0 to x-1.
So you want a random number between 0-3 so use arc4random() % 4;

Then store this random value in an int and use that to increment.

for instance

int currentNum = -1;

[self incrementNum];

void incrementNum()
{

```
if (currentNum == -1)
    currentNum = [self getRandomNumber];
else if (currentNum < 5)
    currentNum++;
```

}

int getRandomNumber()
{

```
return arc4random() % 4;
```

}

EDIT::

From reading what you have said above i think i missunderstood. Do you want that array to be randomly sorted so the 4 questions could come out of the array in order such as: 2,4,1,3

If so then you want something like:

//QuestionArray[] contains the questions from 0-4
// NewQuestionArray[] will contain the new randomly ordered questions
// If first loop then that question won't have appeared before
// If on i >= 1 then loop through previous numbers to see if that question has appeared, if it has store it then increment i
int i = 0;

while (i < 5)
{

```
 int newNum = [self getRandomNumber];
 if (i == 0)
 {
    NewQuestionArray[i] = QuestionArray[newNum];
    i++;
 }
 else
 {
    BOOL repeatNum = FALSE;
    for (int p = 0; p < i; p++)
    {
        if (newNum == NewQuestionArray[i])
        {
             repeatNum = TRUE;
        }
    }
    if (!repeatNum)
    {
       NewQuestionArray[i] = QuestionArray[newNum];
       i++;
    }
 }
```

}

Code might not be great but should give you an understanding. I haven't explained the code as i haven't really included anything in there that isn't basic. But i can explain it better if you want me to.

Comment: i am getting the following error when I try using the last edit you supplied. It states "invalid operands to binary ==" so im not sure what to use now?

Comment: well i guess you would want 

if (QuestionArray[newNum] == NewQuestionArray[i])

Comment: Well this depends what type your QuestionArray[] is using. If it contains a string then i guess you would want: if ([[QuestionArray objectAtIndex:newNum] isEqualTo:[NewQuestionArray objectAtIndex:i]])